# Vetores ou Matrizes em C/C++

Tags: c, c++

segue abaixo um problema podendo usar vetores ou matrizes, eu tenho uma duvida de como fazer o item 1 do menu, se alguem puder me explicar, agradeceria muito :)

A faculdade X pensou em adotar armários para os alunos deixarem seus materiais, da mesma forma que as universidade Americanas. Com isso, ela pensou nos alunos de Engenharia da Computação para montar a automação deste sistema. Para testar o sistema terá que controlar 10 armários. Monte um menu de opções que será exibido num display de controle conforme o exemplo abaixo e implemente as rotinas para que cada opção do menu funcione corretamente:

MENU

1 – Mostrar a situação de todos os armários, exemplo: Armario 0: Ocupado, Armario 1: Ocupado, Armario 2: Livre...

2 – Mostrar os armários livres, exemplo: Armario 2, Armario 4, Armario 8...

3 – Utilizar Armário: Informar o número de um armário livre e marcá-lo como ocupado, caso o armário estiver ocupada avisar o usuário ARMARIO SENDO UTILIZADO.

4 – Remover Armário: Informar o número de um armário ocupado e fazer a liberação do armário, caso o armário estiver livre avisar o usuário ARMARIO NAO ESTA SENDO UTILIZADO.

5 – Resumo do Armário, exemplo: 3 Armários livres, 7 Armários ocupados

0 - Sair

Observações: O programa deve iniciar com todos os Armários livres e o menu deve ficar em loop infinito, ou seja, depois de escolher qualquer opção deve sempre voltar ao menu. O menu deve tratar opções inválidas.

Comment: Pode mostrar até onde você chegou na codificação? Se deu algum problema ou se tem dúvida em algum conceito específico?

Comment: eu tenho uma duvida sobre o conceito de vetores mesmo, se puder dar uma ajudinha, agradeceria muito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia criar um vetor do tipo bool, que vai armazenar se o armario está vazio ou não:

```
bool armarioOcupado[10] = {false, false, ... //Inicializar todos em falso
```

> 1 – Mostrar a situação de todos os armários, exemplo: Armario 0: Ocupado, Armario 1: Ocupado, Armario 2: Livre...

```
#include <iostream>...


int numArmario = 4;//Numero do armario escolhido
if(armarioOcupado[numArmario] == true)
{
    std::cout << "Armario " << numArmario << ": Ocupado";
    //Saída: Armario 4: Ocupado
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Armario " << numArmario << ": Livre";
}
```

Aí coloca essa parte em um loop para facilitar a mostrar todos sem ficar no Ctrl+C e Ctrl+V.